# Conflict between Spring MVC and JSTL on Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jstl, conflict

I am currently looking about Spring MVC on Maven and, just for a test, I decided to try out a basic connection page. I figured out I needed JSTL, so i added it to the dependencies in my pom.xml, but every time I try to restart my Tomcat server after this I get this error :

```
Could not delete D:/IDE/java-neon/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/HelloWeb/WEB-INF/lib. May be locked by another process.
```

Does anyone know what should I do for this please ?

Comment: I sounds like the IDE or Plugin has a the lib folder open, and therefore it can't be deleted. Pretty sure this has nothing to do with JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

Well I deleted Tomcat server and the runtime configurations, restarted eclipse and I figured out that the problem was solved. Still don't know what kind of error this could be, but whatever.